# Why doesn't a delete increase unused space in a table?

Tags: sql-server, delete, tablespaces

If I populate the following table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.CleanTableTest', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.CleanTableTest;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.CleanTableTest
    (FileName nvarchar(4000), 
    DocumentSummary nvarchar(max),
    Document varbinary(max)
    );
GO
-- Populate the table with data from the Production.Document table.
INSERT INTO dbo.CleanTableTest
    SELECT REPLICATE(FileName, 1000), 
           DocumentSummary, 
           Document
    FROM Production.Document;
GO

exec sp_spaceused CleanTableTest
go
```

Results:

```
name           rows  reserved  data    index_size  unused
-------------- ----  --------- ------- ----------- ------
CleanTableTest 13    456 KB    440 KB  8 KB        8 KB
```

But then if I delete all the rows:

```
delete dbo.CleanTableTest
go

exec sp_spaceused CleanTableTest
go
```

Results:

```
name           rows reserved data   index_size unused
-------------- ---- -------- ------ ---------- -------
CleanTableTest 0    88 KB    80 KB  8 KB       0 KB
```

Why after the delete process of all rows in table the unused space have not changed? It stays at 0 KB.

Comment: You need to rebuild. Delete marks rows for deletion but this doesn't even really happen immediately. But even when that does happen, it may remove some percentage of a page but it doesn't optimize or consolidate the pages.

Comment: maybe the questions should be : what is unused space in table/object/database ?

Comment: You also must note pages are never physically deleted they are marked as de-allocated in IAM pages and accordingly PFS page is updated so pages internally hold the data they would eventually be cleaned out

Comment: Try `delete dbo.CleanTableTest WITH (TABLOCKX)`. This may allow empty pages to be released from the heap (assuming the database does not have snapshot isolation or read committed snapshot enabled.)

Comment: Yes. You are right. But why is it ? very intresting . thanks .

Answer (score 8):

You have a heap. Heaps don't clear out space with `DELETEs` in most cases. You could truncate the table, or you could put a clustered index on the table. Heaps are great for insert-heavy systems, but not great if there are lots of deletes.

Comment: Are you sure about the HEAP table ? please run this : create table test2 (col1 int);
go
insert into dbo.test2 (col1) values (1);
go 200

sp_spaceused test2;
go
create clustered index test2_jfvghf on   test2 (col1);
go
delete top(4) test2;
go
sp_spaceused test2;
go
delete  test2;
go
sp_spaceused test2;
go

Comment: What are you trying to show me, Itzik? A heap doesn't release row pages from delete statements (though your LOB storage will get reduced when you delete your nvarchar(max) values. A clustered index does a lot more self management around empty pages.

Comment: Even with truncate( when done for big table) space wont be released immediately and you might as well need to run dbcc shrikfile command

Comment: The file won't shrink, but the space previously used by the table can be used for other data.

Comment: Rob,Thanks for your NOTE, but I asked why the delete process isn't creating Unused space.

Comment: ...because the heap is still using it.

Answer (score 7):

You really need to look at the definition of `sp_spaceused` to find your answer of why `unused` is zero.

```
exec sp_helptext 'sp_spaceused';
go
```

Take a look at a snippet here of the stored procedure:

```
begin
    /*
    ** Now calculate the summary data. 
    *  Note that LOB Data and Row-overflow Data are counted as Data Pages.
    */
    SELECT 
        @reservedpages = SUM (reserved_page_count),
        @usedpages = SUM (used_page_count),
        @pages = SUM (
            CASE
                WHEN (index_id < 2) THEN (in_row_data_page_count + lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count)
                ELSE lob_used_page_count + row_overflow_used_page_count
            END
            ),
        @rowCount = SUM (
            CASE
                WHEN (index_id < 2) THEN row_count
                ELSE 0
            END
            )
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
    WHERE object_id = @id;

    /*
    ** Check if table has XML Indexes or Fulltext Indexes which use internal tables tied to this table
    */
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM sys.internal_tables WHERE parent_id = @id AND internal_type IN (202,204,211,212,213,214,215,216)) > 0 
    BEGIN
        /*
        **  Now calculate the summary data. Row counts in these internal tables don't 
        **  contribute towards row count of original table.
        */
        SELECT 
            @reservedpages = @reservedpages + sum(reserved_page_count),
            @usedpages = @usedpages + sum(used_page_count)
        FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p, sys.internal_tables it
        WHERE it.parent_id = @id AND it.internal_type IN (202,204,211,212,213,214,215,216) AND p.object_id = it.object_id;
    END

    SELECT 
        name = OBJECT_NAME (@id),
        rows = convert (char(11), @rowCount),
        reserved = LTRIM (STR (@reservedpages * 8, 15, 0) + ' KB'),
        data = LTRIM (STR (@pages * 8, 15, 0) + ' KB'),
        index_size = LTRIM (STR ((CASE WHEN @usedpages > @pages THEN (@usedpages - @pages) ELSE 0 END) * 8, 15, 0) + ' KB'),
        unused = LTRIM (STR ((CASE WHEN @reservedpages > @usedpages THEN (@reservedpages - @usedpages) ELSE 0 END) * 8, 15, 0) + ' KB')

end
```

That's copied directly from the definition of `sp_spaceused`.  Take note of how `unused` is actually defined:  reserved pages subtracted by used pages (provided reserved pages is greater than used pages, rationally and programmatically).

So that is why your `unused` column is what it is.  Reverse engineering will explain it all.